# kafka-node setting producer options

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka

I don't know maybe I am completely stupid and can't read documentation anymore. But I am clueless how to set options for producers.

The documentation you can find here looks like this for a producer:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node

```
const options = {
    requireAcks: 1,
    ackTiimeoutMs: 100,
    partitionerType: 2
}
const producer = new HighLevelProducer(client, options);
```

Am I really not allowed to set other options for a producer? Because the number of options I can find on https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/ is very long. 
I would like to set options like `enable.idempotence: true` 
for my producer.

Thanks for the helps

Comment: I have a strange feeling `kafka-node` library does not support idempotence?  https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/blob/4a5a767328695558dc50fbf2d3370cf0cc0fe0a7/types/index.d.ts#L164-L168  Have you been able to figure out how to enable this in nodejs?

Comment: will give `https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka` a try....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const kafkaConf = {  
  "bootstrap.servers" : "localhost:9092",
  "key.serializer" : "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
  "value.serializer" : "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
  ...
  ...
  "enable.idempotence" : true,
  ...
};

const topic = <topic-name>;
const producer = new Kafka.Producer(kafkaConf);
```

**Note**: The three dots {...} are just placeholders for you to add any more properties in your producer. I've just picked some of the basic ones.

I hope this helps!

Comment: which kafka nodejs library are you using?   `kafka-node` does not seem to support idempotence: https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/blob/4a5a767328695558dc50fbf2d3370cf0cc0fe0a7/types/index.d.ts#L164-L168